# I can not access my notebook with my Android using IPv4

Tags: android, android-emulator, xampp, ip, wampserver

I'm having a bad problem and it already gave me a headache. I did an application with Magic Software and to run it on my Android I have to configure Magic Studio the right way (done), run the project on the Magic server (done and working) and install MagicDev.apk on android (available in the Magic XPA folder and already done), and when finished installing, the application must be run and when it is executed it asks to enter the URL of the Magic application, which is the following: http://[IPv4_of_notebook]/MagicScripts/DevProps.txt, but when you try to access this, it is not possible, it says that the application was not found or the connection failed.

It is worth mentioning, I had this same access problem when using XAMPP or Wamp, because when trying to access the localhost with the cell phone, the link would not respond, it would load until I gave the message (I put Wamp online for this, of course, and changed the settings in the [files].conf). Another important thing is that I made an Android application in Android Studio where one of its functions was to access the internet and although the application installed on Android really could not connect to the link, the emulator accessed quietly (the emulator runs inside the pc, would there be anything?) and I could do what I had to do, this link was on a page I made using Wamp, that is, the emulator accessed my IP, and the cell phone can not.

My question: Is this some configuration of the notebook, Android, Internet router or am I doing something wrong? My friend created a page using Wamp, configured it correctly and placed it online and from my home, with his IP, I accessed the page (with my notebook) in a quiet way. One more note, my notebook connects to the internet with Wifi and my Android too, meaning they are not connected to the source directly as my room PC is, and I do not know if that also matters.

I will later try to run the application on my PC from the room and see if it gives him access to his IPv4, but I do not think it will work either. Anyway, does anyone have any idea what it can be? I do not like messing with my notebook's Internet and other settings without knowing what I'm actually doing, I'm afraid to make my notebook vulnerable. Here in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1njzFq07t2U you can see the process I'm describing here, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry for the inconvenience, but it's really urgent. I need to know this to continue my study and finish reading the course, otherwise I will be fired.

Comment: It's not an inconvenience - I am asking you to refrain from pressurising _volunteers_ into helping. [Please read this also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326576/472495): _Volunteer readers are, in general, sympathetic to people who have limited employment protections or who might genuinely be at risk of losing a client that is critical to their income. Nevertheless, this is one of the most emotionally manipulative phrases that can possibly be added: good people can easily be suckered into providing help that they themselves do not have time or energy for._

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured out the villain, it was the firewall. When I turned it off everything worked as expected. I can not keep it turned off for security reasons, but from what I've seen I can configure it to accept only my phone.